# Particular solution to Second Order Linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the PDE $c=\frac{y^2}{n^2}(\frac{1}{2}V_{xx}-V_y)$ where $c>0$, $n>0$, $V(x,y):\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_{++}\to \mathbb{R}$. Now, as it is linear, I understand that finding a particular solution and the solution for the homogeneous case will give me the solution.

I already found the solution to the homogeneous one by separation of variables and using some of the boundary conditions I have, which is $V(x,y)=\alpha\exp(\sqrt{\lambda}x+\frac{\lambda}{2}y)$, for some constants $\alpha>0$ and $\lambda>0$.

Where I'm stuck is in the particular solution. I'm not familiar with the techniques needed to recover it, so any help is more than welcomed.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: A very particular solution is obtained by $V_p=V(y)$ which yields $V_p=\frac{cn^2}{y}+k$. Not sure if that helps with regards to your BCs though...